# Achieve animated seesaw -ish effect with linear-gradient (pure CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, css-transitions

I have an element with one diagonal side achieved by adjusting linear-gradient and height - in two different states. Now I try to toggle between these states and have a smooth transition of the red triangle, so that it would look like a seesaw :-) The problem is, that from one state to another it changes the direction and is jumpy, I did not find a way to animate it fluently .. Is there a way to to what I want using pure CSS e.g. using transitions?

```js
let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
let stage = document.getElementById('stage');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  stage.classList.toggle('fixie');
});
```

```css
body,
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#stage {
  width: 100%;
  height: 14em;
  background: pink;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#stage::before {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  /*as high as #stage*/
  opacity: 0.4;
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  background: linear-gradient(to left bottom, red 50%, pink 50%);
  /*transition: height 4s;*/
  /*transition: linear-gradient 4s 8s;*/
}

#stage.fixie::before {
  height: 30%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, red 50%, pink 50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="stage"></div>
<button>animate gradient</button>
```

Here is my [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/gema9g35/34/)

Comment: Did you already checked with CSS3 and keyframes?

Comment: Do you want it to look like your fiddle, just without it being triggered via JS? Or what exactly is it supposed to look like?

Comment: sorry for not being clear: The JS to change class is OK, the 2 states are OK, but the transition from one state to the other should be smooth, so the *red triangle should behave like a "seesaw"* .. From how it looks like with the class to without the class :-/ I hope this is more understandable?

Comment: Sadly it is not possible to animate backgrounds with the `transition` property (`background-image`  or `linear-gradient`), so you have to "cheat"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can't animate `linear-gradient`, here is a workaround using `transform`

In this sample I used `skew`. As the degree of skew will differ based on the width/height, and as long as its ratio is kept, this will be fully responsive, else you'll need a small script.

```js
(function(){
 let btn = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
 let stage = document.getElementById('stage');
 
 btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
    stage.classList.toggle('fixie');
 });
})();
```

```css
body, ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#stage {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 90vw;
  height: calc(90vw * 0.2677);     /*  0.2677, aspect ratio that match skew degree  */
  background: pink;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.navi {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 4em;
  height: auto;
  background: green;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}
#stage::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%; /*as high as #stage*/
  bottom: 100%;
  opacity: 0.4;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
  transform: skewY(15deg);
  transform-origin: left bottom;
  transition: transform 2s;
}
#stage.fixie::before {
  transform: skewY(-15deg) translateY(100%);
}
.navi ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  background:  lightblue;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
.navi ul li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  min-width: 4em;
  width: auto;
  height:  2em;
  margin: 1px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id="stage"></div>
<button>
animate
</button>
```

---

*Side note:*

One can use any fixed value instead of `vw`, as long as the `#stage`'s ratio is kept. If to change ratio, you'll either need a script, since `CSS calc` can't do math with `sqrt` and `sin`/`cos` etc. to get the angle, or using media query's, and have angle's and ratio's manually set for different screens.

Comment: thx for your answer - it's a pity it seems it has to be done like this, because I would have loved to find a **responsive pure css solution**..

Comment: wow.. thank you very much, *calc* and *vw* did this?! I updated the [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/hoffs/gema9g35/45/) with your approach

Comment: @ho.s Yes, `calc()` and `vw`, but you can use any fixed value instead of `vw`, as long as the `#stage`'s ratio is kept. If to change ratio, you'll need a script since `calc` can't do math with `sqrt` and `sin` to get the angle.

Comment: @ho.s With media query's you could use another angle and ratio to make it look better on smaller and bigger screens